# Why doesn't os.normpath collapse a leading double slash?

Tags: python, filepath

Under Unix, *os.path.normpath* collapses multiple slashes into single ones **except when exactly two slashes appear that the start of the path**.  Why the exception?

To illustrate, I get the following transformations:

```
//double/slash/stays -> //double/slash/stays
/double/slash//gone// -> /double/slash/gone/
double//slash//gone/ -> double/slash/gone
///triple/slash/gone -> /triple/slash/gone
////quad/slash/gone -> /quad/slash/gone
```

This seems strange to me.  I can vaguely imagine this is useful for SMB mounts or URLS, but I don't think I care about those.  Is there any hidden wisdom to Python's behaviour, or should I just collapse the leading // myself?

**[update]**
In view of the answer below, it looks like the best thing is not to collapse the //, but to either just accept it, or to treat it as an error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because POSIX allows treating a path beginning with two slashes in an implementation-defined manner. In other words, //foo does not necessarily mean the same thing as /foo on all POSIX systems.

From [IEEE Std 1003.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11):

> A pathname that begins with two successive slashes may be interpreted
> in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading
> slashes shall be treated as a single slash.

See also [this bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue636648) (which was closed as "not a bug").

Comment: Can you give an example of this? I am quite interested to see how i can implement this in my Linux system ;)

Comment: As far as I know, Linux doesn't take advantage of this fact. "Implementation-defined" means the implementation can do whatever it wants, including treating the double slash just like a single slash.

Comment: Interesting.  Now it is POSIX rather than Python who's wisdom is hidden.  Someone, somewhere in the unix world must use (or once have planned to use) the // prefix -- and then lobbied POSIX to make this strange rule.  Any ideas what the intent is or was?

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala I don't really know what this is used for. I always suspected that it was intended for things like virtual file systems (eg: //ftp/host/path), remote file systems (eg: //hostname/path) or perhaps even some kind of weird backup or revision control system (eg: //timestamp/path). The only thing I've seen in practice that resembles this is UNC pathnames in Windows. Windows pathnames aren't POSIX compliant in general, though, so I assume that's just a coincidence.