# POSIX path 1003.1 - examples and behaviour for '//foo/bar'

Tags: python, path, posix

I am currently implementing a filesystem scanner in Python (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfilesysobjects), and recognized the specifics from POSIX with leading double slash '//'. But I cannot find current examples.

I already read:

- [gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/11947](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/11947)
- [bugs.python.org](https://bugs.python.org) - Issues [26329](http://bugs.python.org/issue26329) and [27228](http://bugs.python.org/issue27228)
- [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com) - [Why doesn't os.normpath collapse a leading double slash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816818/why-doesnt-os-normpath-collapse-a-leading-double-slash)
- [pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html)

But still looking for uptodate information and examples with real world application. Even though I guess I worked with the RFS early 90's, I do not remember.

The most important question for me is what to do when the special app is absent, so can I implement the behavior as a filesystem path as default?
Or has it to be an error?

Comment: I dunno about current systems, but there was a time when some systems interpreted `//machine/path/to/file` as designating a file on a different machine from the current machine.  Once upon a time, there was a networking system called The Newcastle Connection which used the notation `/../machine/path/to/file` to connect to another machine.

Comment: Thanks,
I  implemented a some core standards initially for SMB/CIFS,UNC, and Posix: https://pythonhosted.org/pyfilesysobjects/path_syntax.html#syntax-elements