# Why does os.path.realpath remove double slashes at the start of the path, while os.path.abspath does not?

Tags: python, unix, path, filepath, os.path

On Linux, with Python 3.8:

| Path | Result of os.path.realpath | Result of os.path.abspath |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '/home' | '/home' | '/home' |
| '//home' | '/home' | '//home' |
| '///home' | '/home' | '/home' |
| '////home' | '/home' | '/home' |

Why do the results differ for `'//home'`?

Comment: Because It's respect the RFC : [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816818/why-doesnt-os-normpath-collapse-a-leading-double-slash?rq=4).